# @Cascade Delete not working (JPA, Hibernate and Spring mvc)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, cascade

I read many posts and guides about this topic, but I'm still not able to make it work.

I'm not able to delete, from the database, a child Entity that has been just removed from the collection of the parent Entity (of course insert and update operations work on my child collection).

In order to make it easier for you to understand, I created a simple code where, as you can see, I get an object **Utente** from the database, I remove an object **Autorizzazioni** from the field **autorizzazioniLista** and finally I saved the object **Utente**.

In the pics, you can see that the object **Autorizzazioni** is removed from the collection.

Here you can see the object **Utente** taken from the database and what there is inside the collection **autorizzazioniLista** (there are 2 **autorizzazioni**: id 8 and id 92).
[image]

Here you can see that an object **Autorizzazioni** (id 8) is removed from the collection **autorizzazioniLista** when the object **Utente** is being saved. 
[image]

Here is **Utente**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "utente")
@Component
public class Utente implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7124540331184173742L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "nome")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z ']*$")
    @NotBlank
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "cognome")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z ']*$")
    private String cognome;

    @Column(name = "email")
    @Email
    @Size(min = 1, max = 70)
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "utente", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Valid
    private Autenticazione autenticazione;  

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "utente", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,  orphanRemoval=true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)    
    private List<Autorizzazioni> autorizzazioniLista;
}
```

this is **Autorizzazioni**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "autorizzazioni")
@Component
public class Autorizzazioni implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1167361558860087705L;      

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id; 

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Utente.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "utente", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 11)
    private Utente utente;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Autorizzazione.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "autorizzazione", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 11)
    private Autorizzazione autorizzazione;
}
```

this is **Autorizzazione**

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name="autorizzazione")
public class Autorizzazione implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1118124214231477185L;         

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private int id; 

    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z.-_ ]*$")
    @Column(name = "descrizione")
    private String descrizione;
}
```

Can anybody spot the error?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the same hibernate `Session` to load the object AND update the collection by removing an element, you need to dissociate the dependent collection entity from his 'owner' by setting the parent object reference to null. Something along the lines:

```
Autorizzazioni autorizzazioni = utente.getAutorizzazioniLista().remove(0);
autorizzazioni.setUtente(null);
session.saveOrUpdate(utente);
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. Actually I've already tried it, but it doesn't work. It just set to null the field utente on relative record of the database. The relative record of Autorizzazioni is not deleted from the database.